# How to fit such a big table in LaTex

Tags: tables, longtable

[image]

How to fit in LaTex just like a long table more than one page? I need some help

Comment: Have a look at package longtable

Comment: Longtable (as @Johannes_B already said) and maybe use landscape pages for the table, this will probably reduce the number of linebreaks in the very narrow columns.

Comment: please also have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `longtabu` package, here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \centering \footnotesize
    \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {X[l .1] X[l .5] X[c .1] X[c .1] X[c .1]}
        \toprule
        \rowfont[c]{\bfseries}
        Number & Requirement & Relation & Value & Unit \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textsl{Continues on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
        1 & asdf & asdf & asdf & asdf \\
    \end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: apparently you admire `tabu` :-). however you should warn op, that this (otherwise powerful) package is not maintained anymore an is buggy. so it can happen, that in some circumstances will not work as expected. the very same solution you can obtain with `longtable` with `p{,,,}` column type or with `ltablex` with `X` column type.

Comment: @Jack Good to hear it is working, can you select this is the correct answer?

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for telling me, I've been using this environment for over a year now and I've had a couple of hiccups, so it might indeed be good to have a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative with use of `ltablex` package.

as `support to columns' headers formatting is used package`makecell`. for more "professional" and oppen look is used`booktabs`for rules in table where i suggest to replace all rules in table body with additional space provided by`\addlinespace`.

further attention is given to formatting long text in cells. since their are narrow their formatting can be improved by use command `RaggedRight` from package `ragged2e` in definition of new column type `L` (see mwe below).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, ltablex}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
%\keepXColumns  % used in cases when contents of all X columns
                % are shorter than their width which you like to preserve

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\small
\sffamily
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {@{}c >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}L l l
                              *{3}{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}L}
                              @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Number}  & \thead{Risk}          & \thead{Likelihood}    & \thead{Severity}
                & \thead{Description}   & \thead{Effect on\\Project}
                                                                & \thead{Solution}\\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\textsl{Continues on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1   & Poor schedule ability & Low           & Hight
    & \lipsum*[11]          & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[11]  \\
    \addlinespace
2   & Poor ability of using software such as Matlab
                            & Hight         & Hight
    & \lipsum*[11]          & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[11]  \\
    \addlinespace
3   & Complexity underestimated
                            & Low           & Medium
    & \lipsum*[11]          & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[11]  \\
1   & Poor schedule ability & Low           & Hight
    & \lipsum*[11]          & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[11]  \\
    \addlinespace
2   & Poor ability of using software such as Matlab
                            & Hight         & Hight
    & \lipsum*[11]          & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[11]  \\
    \addlinespace
3   & Complexity underestimated
                            & Low           & Medium
    & \lipsum*[11]          & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[11]  \\
\end{tabularx}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

top of the first page:

[image]

bottom of the first page and top of the second:

[image]

Comment: @Jack, please compare bot answer with your real data and than be so kind and inform me, why accepted answer better fulfill your expectation. I like to learn more about people expectations.