# Multi-pages long tables : how to deal with itemize listing?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, ltablex, sidewaystable

I would like to create a multi-pages table similar to this answer on stackexchange ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419760/129702 ) but with the following differences :

- I have 4 columns ("Site", "Description", "Avantages, "Disavantages")
- The two first columns contains text : the two last contains itemize listings
- I don't want the itemize listings to be difficult to read (because of restricted column size) so I am open if needed to merge the two last columns into a single one ("Avantages & Disavantages") and itemize with + / - symbol
- Itemize settings can be strict to limit the empty spaces (nosep,noitemsep,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,after=\vspace*{2pt})
- Any ideas to reduce the space taken by the table would be appreciated

Additional information :

- the "Site" is a simple site name (example: "Hackerrank")
- the "Description" is a short introduction of the site (example: \lipsum*[3])
- In average, there is 5 items in "advantages"
- In average, there is 3-4 items in "disavantages"
- documentclass : report

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please show an example of such a table. How many entries are there in the advanteges/disadvantages part? How much text will there be in the first two columns? Which documentclass do you use? (The available space depends on the documentclass)

Comment: Probably you could even use a `description` environment (for "Site"  and "Description"  and a nested itemize for the advantages/disadvantages part?

Comment: I add some details : you could use lipsum for that (in average, items could be remplaced by lipsum[1] or lipsum[2] most of the time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which defines two new columns with compact lists. I pretty sure that it is based on a answer by Heiko Oberdiek, but I was not able to find the answer to give correct reference.

One column is defined as a itemize list, one is defined as a numbered list. You can change the width of the list columns at will. If you prefer that the tabular fills the space between the margin, you can use `\extracolsep{\hfill}`. You may also use [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular).

If the heading shall be repeated at each page, just use the normal [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) commands. To cancel enumeration or itemisation for individual cells, you use `\multicolumn`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, longtable, booktabs}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{%--- Enumerated cells ---
   >{\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
     \NoHyper%                Hyperref adds a vertical space
     \let\\\tabularnewline
    \settowidth{\leftmargini}{\,9.\hspace{\labelsep}}
     \enumerate
        \addtolength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 50pt}% for raggedright
        \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}%
   p{#1}%
   <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\endenumerate
     \endNoHyper
     \endminipage}}

\newcolumntype{i}[1]{%--- Itemized cells ---
   >{\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
        \let\\\tabularnewline
        \settowidth{\leftmargini}{~\hspace{\labelsep}}
        \itemize
           \addtolength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 50pt}%
           \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}%
   p{#1}%
   <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\enditemize\endminipage}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{}%
        {\let\NoHyper\relax\let\endNoHyper\relax}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{2cm}p{2cm}i{3.5cm} e{3.5cm}@{}}
\toprule
Site & Description & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Avantages} & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{Disavantages}\\
\midrule\endhead %% Repead heading on every page
Text here and there & More left aligned text &
  \item Item A is part of a itemised list
  \item Item B   &
  \item Item 1 is part of a numbered list
  \item Item 2   \\
\midrule
Text & Text &
  \item Item A
  \item Item B   &
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
    \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 1
   \\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailled answer : the heading shall be repetead as I doubt 6 sites with itemize stuff will fit in one page ^^

Comment: @jy95 Do you need separate first page heading? Footer?

Comment: No footer is needed : with 6 sites, the table is a little bit for that

Comment: @jy95 If the `Site` column is only one line, you may change the first `p{2cm}` with an `l`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using nested desctiption and itemize lists. The layout can be further customized using the `enumitem` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setlist[itemize]{label=+.,leftmargin=*, nosep}
\begin{description}
\item[a term]\lipsum[3]
\begin{itemize}
\item[+] \lipsum[1][1]
\item[+] \lipsum[1][1]\lipsum[1][2] \lipsum[1][3]
\item[--] \lipsum[1][1]
\item[--] \lipsum[1][1]\lipsum[1][2] \lipsum[1][3]
\end{itemize}
\item[another term]\lipsum[5]
\begin{itemize}
\item[+] \lipsum[1][1]
\item[+] \lipsum[1][1]\lipsum[1][2] \lipsum[1][3]
\item[--] \lipsum[1][1]
\item[--] \lipsum[1][1]\lipsum[1][2] \lipsum[1][3]
\end{itemize}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```